# How widely supported are background-size and background-origin?

Tags: css, background-image

And which browsers require a prefix: `-moz-background-size`, `-webkit-background-size`, and similar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [CanIUse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size) for a table showing browser support for this feature for all browsers and versions in common use.

Short answer: IE6/7/8 don't support it. Firefox 3.6 requires `-moz-` prefix. Older versions of safari might have issues. Everywhere else it should work just fine.

Comment: - Thanks for the perfect answer, esp for the caniuse.com reference.

Answer (score 4):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-size

Chrome supports it directly since 3.0; Firefox since 3.6; IE since 9.

Comment: Thanks, Pekka. I never remember developer.mozilla.org but now I hope I will.