# Problems With Background-Size

Tags: background, css

I'm trying to make a percentage bar for iOS, so I couldn't use the `<input type="range" />`, then I'm doing it like this:

```
<div id="detailedPercentage">
    <div id="percLabel">70%</div>
</div>
```

With this CSS, where `perc.png` is a `1px` colored with `rgb(136, 153, 170)`:

```
#detailedPercentage {
    height: 32px;
    width: 286px;
    margin-right: 15px;

    border: 1px solid #222;
    background-image: url(../images/perc.png);
    background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size: 70%;
}

#percLabel {
    height: 32px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #222;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Georgia;
    line-height: 32px;
    font-size: 19px;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

But the background is filling 100% of the box. What should I do to correct this?

Comment: I think that `background-repeat` is what the problem is. `background-size` appears to manipulate the image itself. http://jsfiddle.net/bxedY/1/

Comment: Just removed the `background-repeat` and nothing changed

Comment: You could use `background-position` instead: http://jsfiddle.net/bxedY/2/ (Note, I didn't have an exactly sized background image. so ignore the actual value.)

Comment: That's because I don't think it does what you want. It will default to `background-repeat: repeat`, so removing it or not removing that statement will have no discernable effect.

Comment: The `background-position` works, but when I try to use `-70%` it inverts the background (starts on white and then goes darker), but if I try `70%` it fills the entire box again

Comment: I'm only having luck with absolute values: http://jsfiddle.net/bxedY/3/ `144px` is 30% of `480px`, which is the background image's width.

Comment: You could, of course, stack some elements, and make the behind element `70%`. http://jsfiddle.net/bxedY/4/

Comment: Thanks very much. The stacking elements solution worked. Could you please make your comment an answer so I can Accept it? **:)**

Comment: Done. `:)` That was actually my first thought, but I figured you wanted to do it with pure css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use stacked elements to make a progress meter.

**HTML** - Note the `percDisplay` element.

```
<div id="detailedPercentage">
    <div id="percDisplay"></div>
    <div id="percLabel">70%</div>
</div>
```

**CSS** - Note the `position` properties.

```
#detailedPercentage {
    height: 32px;
    width: 480px;
    margin: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #222;
    background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
    position: relative;
}
#percDisplay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: rgb(136, 153, 170);
    width: 70%;
    height: 32px;
}
#percLabel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 32px;
    width: 100%;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Georgia;
    line-height: 32px;
    font-size: 19px;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bxedY/4/

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same css problem (though not related to IOS) a couple of months ago and asked the question over here:

[background-position question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6776690/background-position-question)

and I also asked this related question:

[How widely supported are background-size and background-origin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547916/how-widely-supported-are-background-size-and-background-origin)

Perhaps those will help.

To see the solution working (on an incomplete, buggy page) take a look at the "Bid x Ask" column (ninth col from left)  in [**this table.**](http://www.sellmycalls.com/cgi-bin/chain)

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to do like the "Bid x Ask" column, but my one uses only one box and it isn't a table

Comment: But the general approach should work for you as well, right? Or not? If not, add a comment and I'll reconstruct what I ended up doing.